# How to use IPictureDisp::Invoke to correctly invoke the Render member

Tags: c, winapi, com, gdi, win32ole

I have a 23x23 bitmap which I'm loading from a file into an instance of the  `IPictureDisp` COM interface. I'm loading the picture using `OleLoadPicture`, passing `IID_IPictureDisp`. Please assume that this is working and returning me a valid pointer to an `IPictureDisp`, from which I am able to get an `IDispatch` pointer without any problem.

I am also able to use `IDispatch::Invoke` to get the values of the `Height` and `Width` members of the picture, which come back as 23 and 23, as expected.

The problem is for some reason using `IDispatch::Invoke` to invoke the `Render` method paints a 23x23 monochrome square instead of the picture I expect. Moreover, the colour of the monochrome square corresponds to the colour of the bottom left pixel of the bitmap (which I assume is the zero-eth pixel of the bitmap).

[image: The bitmap I'm trying to render, at 23x23 and blown up to 92x92]

[image: What actually paints to the DC. Note that it is a 23x23 image corresponding to the colour of the bottom left pixel of the desired picture]

*The upper image is the bitmap I'm using (at normal size, and blown up to 4x its size so you can see the colours). The lower image is what is actually rendered.*

I think that the problem likely has to do with how I'm calling `IDispatch::Invoke`.

What I want to do is (pseudocode):

```
pic.Render(hdc, x, y, w, h, 0, h-1, w, -h, &rc)
```

where `rc` is a `RECT` structure that looks like: `left => x ; top => y ; right => x + w ; bottom => y + h`.

The C code that eventually gets called is equivalent to this:

```
// NOTE: x = 0, y = 0, w = 23, h = 23, and -h => 0xffffffe9 in a 32-bit int
DISPPARAMS args = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
args.cArgs = 10;
args.rgvarg = (VARIANT *)alloca(10 * sizeof(VARIANT));
int values[10] = { (int)hdc, x, y, w, h, 0, h-1, w, -h, (int)&rc };
for (int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
{
    V_VT(args.rgvarg[10-k-1]) = VT_I4;
    V_I4(args.rgvarg[10-k-1]) = values[k];
}

VARIANT result;
VariantInit(&result);

// assume dispid is the correct DISPID for the "Render" method
HRESULT hresult = idisp->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &args, &result, NULL, NULL);
```

The value of `hresult` is 0 (`S_OK`) when the call returns, but picture rendered is the monochrome image I've shown, using only the colour from the bottom left-hand corner of the image.

How am I misusing `IDispatch::Invoke`?

Comment: `Render` is not automation-compatible, I'm pretty sure you can't call it via `Invoke`. Any reason you can't just query for `IPicture` and call `Render` the regular (early-bound) way?

Comment: I'm definitely succeeding in calling it via `Invoke`, and the proof is that it puts bits on the DC in the exact spot I asked for. Sadly the reason I can't use `IPicture` and early-bind to `IPicture::Render` is that this is running through a scripting engine which I excised for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I remember it now.  The parameters for `Render` are confusing.  The source values are in himetric values, and not in pixels.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693441%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Essentially, it's only using a few pixels as the source, instead of the whole image.

My suggestion is you get the himetric width/height using `get_Width` and `get_Height`.  Or use `AtlPixelToHiMetric` to convert them:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/8ca5swet%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I feel stupid, because I *knew* this, and I only missed it because I mis-ported the code. (So I thought I was handling it right even when I wasn't!). Thank you SO MUCH for making me go back and look at this again!

Answer (score 0):

I really think we can't assume that you're loading the image correctly.  Examine that, and see.  I've had issues like this where I assumed it was the rendering code, when it in fact was the image loading code.  Ensure that your source data is of perfect quality, and find a way to examine the data once it's loaded.  I think you may be surprised as to what you find.

Comment: Good advice -- thx PhoenixX. I just tried `QueryInterface`'ing an `IPicture` interface off of the `IDispatch` and calling render directly and it's still giving the same corrupt image. Double-checking my loading code.

Comment: I was able to verify that it's loading right by `QueryInterface`'ing the `IPicture`, calling `IPicture::SaveAsFile`. It creates an exact copy of the original file.